can we integrate snapchat's conversion API in flutter app?
i am wondering if we can integrate Snapchat conversion API in Flutter app, as I was reading through docs I found that

Business SDK
The Business SDK is an SDK that facilitates requests and authentication processes with CAPI as if they were local functions
of the supported languages. This will largely simplify the integration
for you as we bundle the dedicated CAPI client, hashing libraries, and
code examples into one SDK that is available in multiple languages.
This should be your first step before beginning the CAPI installation
process. We highly recommend using Business SDK if you are starting a
new CAPI integration.
We currently support the following languages: Go, Java, PHP, Python
and Ruby.

please see attached file
